# triggered button cause fullpostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I've got an updatePanel and a button which triggered in it.
However, the button causes full postback instead of partial one.
Here's my Code:

```
<asp:Button ID="cEvent" runat="server" Text="&#1510;&#1493;&#1512; &#1497;&#1493;&#1501;" Width="80px" 
                    Height="40px" Font-Size="Medium" onclick="cEvent_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel id = "updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cEvent" EventName="Click"/>
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>

                            <div id="yesEve" runat="server" visible="false" style="width:95%; float:right; margin-left:5%; padding-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                                <table id="mytable" cellspacing="0" runat="server">

                                </table>
                            </div>

                            <div id="errorMsg" runat="server" visible="false" style="width:100%; text-align:center; float:right;">
                                <asp:label visible="true" ID="msg1" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text = "היום נמחק בהצלחה"></asp:label>
                            </div>

                            <div id="noEve" style="width:100%; padding-top:20px; float:right; text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px;" runat="server" visible="false">
                                <asp:label visible="true" ID="stamLabel" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text = "לא קיימים ימים פתוחים"></asp:label>
                            </div>

                            <asp:LinkButton ID ="remove" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>

                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I really need some help with that... i'm searching for hours all over the web to find an answer.
Thanks, Matan

Comment: what version of visual studio and IIS you are using

Comment: Your mark-up works as expected. I tested it (as is) and the button click generates a partial post back. If your page contains more than you have posted, you could try creating a new page using just the mark-up posted and see if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

In the code behind, you can try adding this line:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(Button1);
```

Comment: that's a link to download the whole project, i'll be glad if you'll be able to take a look at it and tell me what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you have a conflict somewhere with code(ClientIDs) you haven't show us or a JavaScript error breaking the page.

Comment: that's a link to download the whole project, i'll be glad if you'll be able to take a look at it and tell me what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template for how to do this from a microsoft tutorial page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Panel created."></asp:Label><br />
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

More information here:

[microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

Comment: @Matan Kadosh: do you have to have the button outside the update panel? I think if you move it inside will generate the "partial postback" -as some people call it-

Comment: this is not all the code.... i've tried all these methods, nothing worked. you can download the full solution here:

Comment: @Matan Kadosh I don't see a link to your source code in the last comment, can you post it again or edit it?